# How can i fix it? sticky navbar working only in first div

Tags: html, css

did i miss something? cause when i scroll down it doesn't go out of div.header
i use position: sticky on  to make it sticky on top but it only working in first div, when i scroll down to second div it stuck and doesn't come out.

html, css https://codepen.io/lightmodeusers/pen/OJZvxzW.

i need you advice, thank you. :)

```
<div class="header">
  <nav>
    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="img\logo.svg" width="213" height="42"></a>
    <div class="nav-links ">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Page 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Page 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CSR</a></li>
        <li><a href="">IS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="header-info">
    <h1>Welcome </h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia, reprehenderit?</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="about">
  <div class="text-about">
    <h1>About</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit nisi praesentium minima omnis amet quo
      eligendi voluptatem. Aliquam quo, illo nobis vitae consectetur corporis exercitationem soluta tenetur
      natus facere. Vero?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the best fix, but in your code, the sticky element (navbar) is inside a container (the first div), thus the sticky will stop once the scroll has passed the container. The quickest way to fix this is to move the navbar outside the `.header` container if possible.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.header {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.5), rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.5)), url("/img/factory1.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  transition: 1s ease;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav-links {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-links ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 0.3rem;
  margin: 0.5px 16px;
}

.nav-links ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.about {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="" class="logo"><img src="img\logo.svg" width="213" height="42"></a>
  <div class="nav-links ">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Product</a></li>
      <li><a href="">CSR</a></li>
      <li><a href="">IS</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="header">

  <div class="header-info">
    <h1>Welcome </h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia, reprehenderit?</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="about">
  <div class="text-about">
    <h1>About</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit nisi praesentium minima omnis amet quo eligendi voluptatem. Aliquam quo, illo nobis vitae consectetur corporis exercitationem soluta tenetur natus facere. Vero?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

though this causes a problem if you want the background of the navbar to be transparent. If that's the case, you could add a negative margin top to the header element so that part of it could become the background of navbar.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `<nav>` is inside of your `<div class="header">`, so it can't escape it.  It's only sticky in reference to the element that it's inside.

Try moving line 1, `<div class="header">` down to right above `<div class=header-info">`.

Comment: I can see what you mean. thank you for knowledge